# How to make the <li> display correctly before jQuery loads?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a `<li>` list that displays several album covers in a jQuery slider. But before the page loads, they get messy. I cannot specify a height and set overflow:hidden due to some album names, that requires more height.

The main CSS used is

```
.container {
background-color: #F9F9F9;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 72%;
  min-height: 315px;}

.container li{
   list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;}
```

[image: Before page loads it gets like this]

The website to see it working is http://testes-hitsebeats.blogspot.com.br/

Comment: You might want to ask an actual question if you'd like to get an actual answer.

Comment: Hello Sean. I want to make they load correctly, using another technique, since I can't use oveflow hidden in this case, because some albuns have more than 3 lines, and it would be hidden. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its better to give HTML code here too.

And try on this method 
your UL container

```
.container {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 72%;
  height: 315px; // Fixed Height
  overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Hello. If I use a specific height, some names will be hidden, in case they need more than 3 lines. I just need to put the <li> side by side, in the same line with an overflow:hidden in the horizontal. Let me know if you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first you should give fixed width to `.conteiner li` then add `box-sizing:border-box;` for padding not to make actual size of `li` larger and finally you should remove all the white spaces between `li` elements

replace :

`<li></li>
<li></li>`

with:

`<li>
</li><li>
</li>`

this is full class

```
.container li{
list-style-type: none;
float:left;
padding: 5px 12px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 20%
}
```

Comment: Should I put box-sizing:border-box; in the .container li? It didn't work :(